# How to reference custom fonts in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I am working on theme customision of login page of keycloak and I am badly stuck at adding the custom fonts on the login page. I don't know how to reference it properly. I am adding this in style tag in login.ftl page. Any sort of help is highly appreciated

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: "Stroke-Weight-Two"!important;
        src: url("../fonts/strokeWeight-080rotateR06.ttf") format("truetype");
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Stroke-Weight-One"!important;
        src: url("../fonts/strokeWeight-080.ttf") format("truetype");
    }
```